# How do I preselect a folder in NSOpenPanel?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsopenpanel

How can I preselect a folder using NSOpenPanel in MacOS Catalina (10.15.7) using Objective C? Setting setDirectoryURL to the required folder path shows the content of the folder at this path, but does not select the folder itself.

Comment: The folder is selected if no containing item is selected.

Comment: Thanks - didn't notice the Open button was enabled even though all the content (files only) was greyed out.